# how can return cv2.imshow() image to browser in django

Tags: django

In `ac` I got the images with their score of similarity in list format.  I want to display all images in browser using django.  How can I display each image in browser?

```
ac=obj.perform(newdoc.docfile.path)
for (score,resultID) in ac:
    result = cv2.imread(path1 + "/" + resultID)
    # cv2.imshow("Result", result)
    return HttpResponse(cv2.imshow("Result", result))
```

From `cv2.show("Result",result)` a popup window is opened and shows the image but when I go through HttpResponse passing the image to the browser it gives the result None.  How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this by one view. I would suggest to have 2 views. first displays single image using StreamResponse. And second view will have a template where it goes trough every image and has `<img>` tag which src shows to your first view.

Also you cannot use cv2.imshow(), I'm not cv2 expert but as far as I know that function is for displaying your image in window. In your case you need to read the binary data from your cv2 object and pass it to StreamResoponse object as django response.

Other possible way is to have a template where you create img tag for each your case and put binary data to it as follows:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{ base64_data_from_cv2_object}}"/>
```